What value to remove background block on text in .dircolors
I want to remove the background color of the text, but I can't seem to find the value in .dircolors. Also I feel like my dircolors are still bound to /usr/bin/dircolors, even though I've done eval "$(dircolors $HOME/.dircolors)" or eval "$(dircolors ~/.dircolors)" on .zshrc



https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code has a large set of color code;
For starters ESC+[4nm, with n being any of 0 to 9 does affect background color.
So, it is might one any of these, or a default:
$ dircolors --bourne-shell | tr ':' '\n' | grep -E '4[0-9]{1}'
pi=40;33
bd=40;33;01
cd=40;33;01
or=40;31;01
su=37;41
sg=30;43
tw=30;42
ow=34;42
st=37;44

This, might give some lead, in color:
$ dircolors --print-ls-colors

